# Laravel make:seeder is very slow

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Why is my `$ php artisan make:seeder` execution very slow?

It always **hangs for more than a minute** after reporting

> Seeder created successfully.

[image: image of console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes It will because of the line in the **SeederMakeCommand.php** file

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Seeds/SeederMakeCommand.php#L62

While You are Running the Command it will **create the New seeder in the Path** and Finally

**Autoloades the Class Files** So That it the Reason it take Some times To finish up the Command

But As you see the SeederFile Will be Generated Instantly